# CDI + EJB in EAR fails: Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I am trying to migrate 2 separate WARs into one **EAR**.

Running on WebLogic 12.2.1, so Java EE 7 (CDI 1.1 and EJB 3.1).

Each WAR contains the same JAR library containing many **@Stateless EJB's** and **@Named CDI managed beans**:

## Situation

```
WAR1
|- WEB-INF/lib/ejb-cdi.jar      (type=jar)
|- WEB-INF/lib/**.jar

WAR2
|- WEB-INF/lib/ejb-cdi.jar      (type=jar)
|- WEB-INF/lib/**.jar
```

In the old situation the 2 WAR's were deployed separately and everything works fine.

Now, I must package the 2 WAR's into 1 EAR file, which will look something like this:

```
EAR
|- WAR1.war                     (skinny, without ejb-cdi.jar)
|- WAR2.war                     (skinny, without ejb-cdi.jar)
|- ejb-cdi.jar                  (type=ejb)
|- lib/**.jar
```

I've performed several required steps:

- changed packaging type to *ejb* for *ejb-cdi.jar* containing the EJB's and CDI managed beans
- configured ejb-cdi.jar as *ejbModule* in pom.xml
- configured WAR1 and WAR2 as *webModule* in pom.xml
- configured the WAR1 and WAR2 as skinny wars without ejb-cdi.jar
- ensured that EJB lookups are succesful by using *@Stateless(mappedName="XX")* and *@EJB(beanName="XX")*

## Problem

EJB lookups work and the EAR starts up. During startup all my CDI *@Inject*s fail with the following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied
dependencies for type MyBean with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private my.package.Foo.myBean
```

After some reading it seems that EJB lookups and CDI injections in EAR files are handled completely different than in plain WAR files.

I assume that since ejb-cdi.jar is not on the classpath in the manifest, the managed beans are not known.

What I have tried:

- Add ejb-cdi.jar to the classpath -> EJB's are now ambiguously defined
- Make ejb-cdi.jar a regular JAR again -> EJB lookups fail entirely
- Add ejb-cdi.jar with a different classifier extra to /lib -> EJB's are now ambiguously defined

(I'm hoping I don't have to reorganize the JAR since I've simplified the situation and in practice there are more than 1 such combined jars..)

**What would be the best solution to get an EAR where EJB and CDI works correctly?**

Comment: Sounds like a classical class loading issue. Let me guess - from within EJB archive you are trying to access (inject) beans in the WAR archive?

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but... can you move packaging from EAR to WAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the end I understood what went wrong:

Some EJB's and CDI managed beans were in the same ejb-cdi.jar JAR. 
Some restructuring of the JARs was done, putting all EJB's in one JAR, putting that as ejbModule in /. This ejbModule did not contain any CDI managed beans any more.

The CDI managed beans JARs ended up inside the WAR or in /lib, depending on what the maven-war-plugin with skinnyWar setting decided, but both ways worked.

**So, the answer is this:**

**Reorganize the EJB and CDI managed beans properly, put them in separate JARs and mark the EJB jar as ejbModule.**